# Realizar consulta - relação many to many - Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize-js

Estou com um problema para realizar uma consulta utilizando o ORM Sequelize.

A estrutura é a seguinte:
Migrations/tabelas: developers, technologies, developers_dechnologies.

A relação entre developers e technologies é many to many, developers_dechnologies utilizo como junção.

Através de um select, preciso retornar todos os developers e todas as technologies atreladas a eles, que possuem a technology "x".

Por exemplo:

Tenho estes 3 devs cadastrados:

```
[
  {
    "id": 96,
    "name": "Jon",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "React"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Messageria"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 97,
    "name": "Doe",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "React"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Javascript"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 98,
    "name": "Mark",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "PHP"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Laravel"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

No front-end o usuário pode filtrar os devs por tecnologia, caso a tecnologia selecionada seja React, preciso que retorne o resultado abaixo, pois, são os únicos devs que possuem react.

```
  {
    "id": 96,
    "name": "Jon",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "**React**"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Messageria"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 97,
    "name": "Doe",
    "technologies": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "**React**"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Javascript"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Na consulta estou fazendo não consigo retornar as outras tecnologias que estão atreladas ao developer, somente a que está na cláusula where. Minha query:

```
  const developers = await Developer.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'name'],
    include: [
      {
        model: Technologies,
        as: 'technologies',
        all: true,
        attributes: ['id', 'name'],
        where: [{ id: tech }],
        through: { attributes: [] },
      },
    ],
```

Entendo que isso acontece justamente por estar selecionando somente a id correspondente a uma tecnologia.. Como eu poderia retornar as outras? Qual seria a lógica correta?

Um print do front-end para entenderem um pouco melhor:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Selecionando somente React:

Aqui eu precisaria além do react, as outras tecnologias atreladas a esse dev.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]